# Undo Pending Change is Trying Checkout

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

For some odd reason, when I attempt to Undo Pending Change, I am getting the error:

> MasterPage.master.designer.vb, MasterPage.master.vb have been
>   automatically checked out for editing. Get latest on checkout is not
>   supported in local workspaces. Checking out the local version.

And:

> some.aspx.designer.vb have been automatically checked out for editing.

I'm trying to undo pending change but it's preventing it and leaving the file(s) checked out without performing any check-in.  Why is this happening, and how do I undo any checkouts?  This is very odd behavior...

Comment: Is the designer making a change (and thus checking out the file)?  What is the difference between your local version and the unmodified workspace version?  What happens if you do the undo with the solution closed?

Comment: Designer did make some sort of change; I can't quite tell why though.  It renamed the namespace of some controls from <ProjectName>.Web to <ProjectName>.<ProjectName>.  Not sure why; I didn't do that, it did.  I just wanted to undo that, but it wouldn't let me.  I manually sync'd the files back to the original and checked it in because undo wasn't working.

Comment: I am not getting this with an code file for an EDMX... very, very strange.